Unable to find `next-intl` locale
I'm using convex auth with nextjs to authenticate in my app, the authentication was working fine, but then I implemented the next-intl, and now I'm getting the following error when logging in:
Unable to find `next-intl` locale because the middleware didn't run on this request. See https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#unable-to-find-locale. The `notFound()` function will be called as a result.

 POST /api/auth 404 in 46ms

This is my middleware.ts:
import createIntlMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import {
  convexAuthNextjsMiddleware,
  createRouteMatcher,
  isAuthenticatedNextjs,
  nextjsMiddlewareRedirect,
} from "@convex-dev/auth/nextjs/server";
import { routing } from "./i18n/routing";

const isPublicPage = createRouteMatcher(["/auth"]);

const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware(routing);

export default async function middleware(request: any) {
  // First, handle internationalization routing
  const intlResponse = await intlMiddleware(request);
  if (intlResponse) {
    return intlResponse;
  }

  // Then, handle authentication routing
  return convexAuthNextjsMiddleware((request: any) => {
    if (!isPublicPage(request) && !isAuthenticatedNextjs()) {
      return nextjsMiddlewareRedirect(request, "/auth");
    }

    if (isPublicPage(request) && isAuthenticatedNextjs()) {
      return nextjsMiddlewareRedirect(request, "/");
    }
  })(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
};

  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "^0.34.2",
    "@convex-dev/auth": "^0.0.61",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.1.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "cmdk": "1.0.0",
    "convex": "^1.15.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^4.12.0",
    "jotai": "^2.9.3",
    "lucide-react": "^0.437.0",
    "next": "^14.2.9",
    "next-intl": "^3.19.1",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "nuqs": "^1.19.1",
    "quill": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-resizable-panels": "^2.1.2",
    "react-use": "^17.5.1",
    "react-verification-input": "^4.1.2",
    "sonner": "^1.5.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },

The next-intl is working, just the convex auth that isnt anymore.
Yes, the middleware is in the src folder.
I've tried multiple middleware configuration on the matcher option, but nothing works
